# Issue installing jhipster-registry

Tags: java, spring, maven, jhipster, jhipster-registry

Excuse my lack of technicality concerning this matter, as i am a solely beginner.
so I'm trying to install a microservice application, so in order to do that , I need to install both gateway and microservice app and linked them through jhipster-registry(correct me if I'm wrong please).
now I've installed both of these apps succesfully. for the gateway I get this message message well presented through html "Your request cannot be processed" when i navigate to the localhost provided by the gateway console while getting this :

```
---------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'gateway2' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:8080/
        External:       http://192.168.56.1:8080/
        Profile(s):     [dev, swagger]
----------------------------------------------------------
2020-05-03 07:08:14.483  INFO 7600 --- [  restartedMain] com.mservice.app.Gateway2App             :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Config Server:  Not found or not setup for this application
----------------------------------------------------------
```

same "Config Server" message I've gotten in the microservice app after the **mvnw** command
issue was when i run **mvnw** in this jhipster-registry folder I get this error in the end, now I've gone through some github issue and found contributors advising to run maven globaly sort of see if it's an environment issue, well nothing changed about the error.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  54.986 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-03T07:00:00Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project jhipster-registry: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

maybe useful informations : I'm using JWT security, PosgreSQL database(and it's succesfully linked), havent implemented any entity in neither of the apps, I'm not using any docker
and if I'm understanding something worng, please point it out I would love for it to make sense.

Comment: Which JDK are you using? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105941/intellij-maven-project-fatal-error-compiling-invalid-flag-release Also you say are a beginner, but in what? JHipster, Spring Boot, microservices?

Comment: I'm a beginner at all of these 3, just picking up basics through documentation, and what you've linked me was right, it was the 1.8 jdk i had so I downloaded the jdk 11 and changed JAVA_HOME variable, it says now that I'm connected to the JHipster Registry config server!
now where do i put the jwt key to avoid the "Full authentication is required to access this resource" in microservice app

Comment: I would advice not to start with microservice architecture, start with monolith in JHipster, you'll have plenty of things to learn first.