# I have a problem uploading my project to heroku: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.12.1:compile

Tags: java, maven, heroku, plugins, upload

I'm trying to upload my project in heroku, but at the last step of the upload I get an error that I don't know how to solve: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.12.1:compile (default -compile) on project RRCB: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]

I searched for it, but the only result that came up didn't help me ([Intellij maven project Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105941/intellij-maven-project-fatal-error-compiling-invalid-flag-release))

I am trying to upload with The Heroku CLIPlease help me I am getting the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.12.1:compile (default-compile) on project RRCB: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RRCB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RRCB</name>
    <description>RRCB</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Spring Boot 3+ required JDK17+ which means the configuration for the maven-compiler-plugin is wrong!

Comment: Then what should it look like? Give me example please.

Answer (score 0):

The whole parts how to configure that setup can be [read within the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started). The resulting configuration should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RRCB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RRCB</name>
    <description>RRCB</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- That looks a bit weird !! -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The defined dependency to `<artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>` does not make sense in a spring boot project because you are not using Maven plugin annotations..

The following part is wrong, because you are overwriting the version from the inherited parent with a different version which is in general a bad idea... You should not define a version. That's handled by the parent or more accurate by the spring-boot-dependencies parts.. That will result in mixing different spring boot versions...I strongly recommend to remove that version number here... and use the one which is provided via the parent:

```
    <dependency> <!-- That looks a bit weird !! -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Furthermore the used modelmapper dependency shows that you are not using the correct one because [the docs of modelmapper contain an example how to use it.](https://modelmapper.org/user-manual/spring-integration/)